# Passport-github js, user-agent error

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, oauth, passport.js

Yesterday I could successfully login in my application via **Passport.js** and **Passport-github** module, today I received such an error:

`500 failed to fetch user profile (status: 403 data: {"message":"Missing or invalid User Agent string. See http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required"})`

So anyone else gets it?

Is it change in gihub oauth policy?

Do we need to contribute to this on **passport-github / node-oauth** modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a user-agent to your Strategy:

```
new GitHubStrategy({
        clientID: <githubClientID>,
        clientSecret: <githubClientSecret>,
        callbackURL: <callback>,
        customHeaders: {"User-Agent" : <your agent string>}
      },
      findOrCreateUserByOAuth
    )
```

Since April, 24th, [User Agent is now mandatory](http://developer.github.com/changes/2013-04-24-user-agent-required/).

Comment: Where do you find this user-agent string?